# Instrumented testing of Android Widget fails

Tags: android

When I try to run my Android instrumented on Google Cloud Platform I get the error:

> Your test artifact is not an android artifact

My app is a Widget and I wonder if that's the reason? It works fine when testing on real device through USB.

Android Studio 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Emulators on Android Studio.

Virtual devices can be created with different combinations, Screen Size and different android versions.

Testing with multiple platforms and different OS versions is very essential to check the compatibility of the Android Applications.

for testing the performance of Android Application you can try with testdroid, load Runner.

Comment: I'm well aware of the need to test of different devices, that's why I try to test on Google Cloud Platform. Running on emulators is not a fix for my problem. Thanks for trying.